# SQL table drop down is missing in VS2019

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2019

Can someone help me how to fix this? As you can see the dropdown menu on the table folder is missing, and I am getting an error. I already installed the SSDT but nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: The error is because `VALUES` requires brackets ('()') around the values being inserted. As an aside please [don't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You need to do `VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Age)`

Comment: Is this correct? I am getting underlines

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member(ID, Name, Age) VALUES(@ID,@Name,@Age"), con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", (textBox2.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", (textBox3.Text));

Comment: `@Age")` needs to be `@Age)"`. Any you should explicitly set the datatype of the parameters, including the length of strings.

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member(ID, Name, Age) VALUES ("@ID,@Name,@Age")", con);

--not working

Comment: I am wondering I cant see my table. Please refer to the image I've posted

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERT INTO member(ID, Name, Age) VALUES ("@ID,@Name,@Age"), con); 

-- i am getting lot of underlines with this code.

Comment: You've asked 2 questions, 1) about the error, 2) about the missing tables. Please ask them separately rather than combined as they have different answers.

Comment: Will do that, Thank you @DaleK. This is the error I'm getting now ---System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a debugging service. The error you posted has been solved. I have no idea what is causing your new issue as you haven't posted enough code. Try googling your new error and/or finding a good tutorial on connecting to the database. And for future reference please post code as formatted text not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to insert values using SqlCommand parameters which I personally use in my projects like shown in this screenshot :

[image]

In your case it would look something like this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO member (ID,Name,Age) VALUES (@ID,@Name,@Age)",con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtage.Text);
```